# How to load a PDF from a Base64 string in a UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, swift3, uiwebview

I'm using an API that is returning a Base64 string, something like this:

```
data:application/pdf;base64,**BASE64STRING**
```

Where BASE64STRING is what I need to display the PDF.

So far I only created a `Data` object that gets the Base64 string:

```
let data = Data(base64Encoded: BASE64STRING)
```

And I tried to load it in the webview:

```
webView.load(data!, mimeType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "", baseURL: URL(string: "")!)
```

The problem is that I don't have a local PDF file, so I don't know what I should put in `baseURL`. Currently it's giving me a `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

How can I load the PDF in the webView? Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: Are you saving the retrieved data locally or you just want to display the data response from the API?

Comment: try passing `"http://localhost/"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem, despite that I'm not sure if it's a good approach, the solution is to put any valid URL in `baseUrl`:

```
webView.load(data!, mimeType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "", baseURL: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!)
```

Comment: can you plz help me. This code is not working for me. Maybe I made a mistake somewhere

Comment: In fact, a few years later when Apple deprecated UIWebView, I had the same weird behavior with WKWebView. I gave it a try with something that had no sense for me as I was trying to present a PDF file created locally, so adding the valid URL made it work. Weird...

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 5, here a complete example with no force unwrapped and temporary file:

```
guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64), let fileUrl = try? saveTemporaryFile(from: data, filename: fileName) else {
    // error handling
    return
}

webView.load(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "", baseURL: fileUrl)
```

And the utility function to save the data in local temp file:

```
func saveTemporaryFile(from data: Data, filename: String? = nil) throws -> URL {
    let filename = filename ?? UUID().uuidString
    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true).appendingPathComponent(filename)
    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileURL)
    try data.write(to: fileURL)

    return fileURL
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
webView.load(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert the base64String to NSData and then convert to Data and use it.

PDF files are binary files so they can't be represented as UITF8 encoded string directly.

```
if let data = NSData(base64Encoded: base64String, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters) as Data? {
    self.webView.load(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", characterEncodingName: "", baseURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: ""))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift 5+
Very Easy and Smooth Solution

```
let base64PDF = "m5hbWVfaWQiOiJ1aWQiLCJRSUQiOiIyNzg1ODYwNDM3NSIsIlVVSUQiOiIwMDE2M0U2Ri1EREMyLTFFRTktQUE5MS0wOEYxMDFEODU4NTYiLCJFbWFpbCI6IlNBSUYuUkVITUFOQEFBQlFBVEFSLkNPTSIs"
if let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64PDF, options: Data.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters) as Data? {
    self.webKitView.load(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", characterEncodingName: "", baseURL: nil)
}
```

Comment: Solution is working and i was wondering for optimise way and i uploaded it.