# Loading PDF from base64 results in empty file url

Tags: ios, swift, data-uri

[Based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45186680/3160679) I'm trying to open a PDF in the web view of my app.

```
private func handlePdf(url: String) {
   // get the base64 encoded part of the url
   let base64String: String = String(url.split(separator: ",")[1])
   let decodeData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
   webView?.load(decodeData!, mimeType: "application/pdf", characterEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: ""))
}
```

The incoming dataurl looks like this: `data:application/pdf;name=test.pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMNCiXi48/TDQolUlNUWFBERjMgUGFyYW1ldGVyczogRF ... JSVFT0YK`

However, the load method of webView is called with `file:///` and absolutely nothing happens.

If I follow [the advice given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43920454/3160679), then safari would simply open with the passed URL (https://www.google.com) in this case.

Any tips and hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Saving it into a temporary file first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67987745/3160679) worked for me.